# How were the state charts drawn in Miro Samek's "Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++"

Tags: diagram, fsm, statechart

What software package was used to draw the statecharts in Miro Samek's "Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++"?

Edit:
Miro Samek provided [excerpts](http://www.state-machine.com/doc/PSiCC2_Excerpts.pdf) from his book on his website. Page 42 of the linked PDF provides an example diagram.

Comment: Can you at least share a picture of the charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All diagrams in the PSiCC2 book have been prepared with Microsoft-Visio 2003. The Visio stencil used in the book is available for a free download from the [companion web-page to the book](http://www.state-machine.com/psicc2/index.html#Visio).

There is also a newer free graphical [modeling tool called QM](http://www.state-machine.com/qm), which you can use to draw diagrams and export to EMF vector format as well as JPG raster format.